# Session is null in MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I find it difficult to do the most common thing in web applications.
I am not able to retrieve the session object.

During Session Start I set the user info in a session variable
Session["CurrentUser] = userInfo;

The userInfo contains the role and the region attributes. Based on these values I dynamically create the menu, in the _Layout.cshtml file

`If Session["CurrentUser"] != null` and I generate the menu.

Here the issue is `Session["CurrentUser"]`  is always `null`.

I added the sessionStatemodule to the web.config and it still did not help.

Please advice on how to get the session.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what if userInfo is null?

Comment: If you can show more of your code like full methods you might be able to get more specific help.

Comment: The application is siteminder enabled.I have used an existing Security component which returns a Session object if the user is authenticated
by siteminder. If the session object is null it is an invalid user.

Comment: Why is my session object null when I try to access it in the _Layout.cshtml to create my header and menu. Any inputs?        Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem as this post.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1622898.aspx?MVC+Session+Variables           It works on my local when I move to production is the problem. Please help